# requirejs or something else for loading/importing js code?

Tags: javascript

given that i would like to better organize my js code i've been looking at requirejs and it looks useful.

more info: http://requirejs.org/

i would like to split js code into several files and finally build a single file (with closure or some similar tool).
so i was wondering what else exists and what would you recommend?

comparison with what different javascript frameworks use to organize their code is appreciated.

Comment: Try ender, modul8, browserify. These use `require` to load modules and build one large package with everything ordered correctly so the dependency chain works.

Answer (score 0):

I started a new application and I decided to organize my code with three libraries:

- **jquery**: DOM, event manipulation... (I also use the put-selector library)
- **requireJS**: create AMD modules and load them. Any bit of code is a module that can declare its own dependencies. Very nice, modular and portable. A lot of big project are moving in that direction, including Dojo.
- **Backbone / Underscore**: it makes your modules so powerful and nice to work with. You have models and collections to work with the data and Views to handle the rendering (it does much more than that).

A very good article to see how orgnization can be done: http://backbonetutorials.com/organizing-backbone-using-modules/

It may look very complicated at first but once set up, it rocks. I couldn't go back to simple js file written in jquery, it was worth the days I spent to get it.